# Variables wont increase, calling non static methods from static method

Tags: java, variables, static, non-static

I am creating a vending machine simulation for a school project and I've been having trouble getting past these first couple barriers. One of the requirements for the project is to have 5 global variables, which i am assuming means variables defined outside any method but within the class. At first, I wasn't able to call upon any of them until I learned about "Static" and "Objects" and I got around that problem by creating instance methods which call upon these variables, and creating an object of these instance methods in my main static method. But the problem is, I need these variables to increment and they won't change from 0!! I'm trying to let the user "insert coins" into the machine but nothing happens when I try it. Anyway, here is the code, it's not anywhere near finished but a little help and clarification on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
package project3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project3 {
       double nickels = 0.00;
       double quarters = 0.00;
       double dimes = 0.00;
       double dollars = 0.00;
       double credits = nickels + quarters + dimes + dollars;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Project3 menu = new Project3();
    menu.menu();
}
public void menu () {
        int counter = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (counter >=0 && counter <=4){
        System.out.print("Credit: "+credits +"\n0. Insert Money \n1. Twix: 50¢ \n2. Marathon Bar: $1.00 \n3. Snickers: 75¢ \n4. Return Change \nSelection: ");
        counter = input.nextInt();
        switch (counter) {
            case 0: getMoney();
                break;
            case 1: 
                break;
            case 2: 
                break;
            case 3: 
                break;
            case 4: 
                break;               
        }
    }
}
public void getMoney(){ 
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (counter >=0 && counter <=4){            
        System.out.print("Credit : " +credits+"\n1. Insert Nickel \n2. Insert Dime \n3. Insert Quarter \n4. Insert Dollar \n5. Return to menu \nSelection: ");
        counter = input.nextInt();
        switch (counter) {
            case 1: nickels += .05;
                break;
            case 2: dimes += .10;
                break;
            case 3: quarters += .25;
                break;
            case 4: dollars += 1.00;      
                break;                    
      }  
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: First of all, to get it to compile, try replacing `.05`, `.10`, `.25` etc. with `0.05`, `0.10` and `0.25`, respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are initializing credits with the values currently stored in nickles, quarters, etc

It does not get updated every time you request it's value

what you need to do is add a function:

```
private double getCredits(){
    return nickels + quarters + dimes + dollars;
}
```

and print getCredits() rather than credits